# Know lower value and its column name from select

Tags: php, sql, select

I have a PHP document with MySQL database storing with the following structure:

- `DATE` FIELD
- 24 `float` values corresponding to the 24 hours. (The name is 1h, 2h, 3h, 4h... 24h)

I fetch a row with the simple select: `SELECT * from table where DATE = "2014-02-02"` obtaining the 25 fields.

I want to know wich field of 1h, 2h, 3h.... has the lower value. I'm trying doing that with PHP and min() function, but I only retreive the value, not the index of the array.

Is this possible a simple way to know this result? Maybe in the SQL function?

Thank you

EDIT: I tried this (Considering $arraySQL has a valid result obtained before):

```
     function ObtainArrayFromSQL($arraySQL){
     $array = array();
     for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++)
          {
              array_push($array, $data_day[$i."h"]);
          }
     return $array;
     }
     [...]

     $array = ObtainArrayFromSQL($arraySQL)
     echo min($array);
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Would be nice to see what you've already tried.

Comment: MySQL, using MySQLi functions, I edit the answer

Comment: `MIN()` function in SQL - try it

Comment: @Alexander he already wrote he tried that

Comment: @Kuzgun he wrote he tried it with some PHP min function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL, you can use the `least()` function:

```
select t.*,
       (case when col1 = leastval then 'col1'
             when col2 = leastval then 'col2'
             when col3 = leastval then 'col3'
             . . .
             when col24 = leastval then 'col24'
        end) as leastvalcol   
from (select t.*,
             least(col1, col2, . . . , col24) as leastval
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Before complaining about all the typing you need, you should know that this query is much more complicated than it needs to be -- because you are storing things on a row that should be in a column.  Your table should have a separate row for each hourly value, rather than putting all the daily values on one row.  With a more normalized structure, your query would be much simpler.

EDIT:

This table would have columns such as:

```
Date date,
Hour time,  -- or int or varchar() depending on how you really want it captured
Value float
```

Then the query might look like:

```
select date, min(value) as minvalue,
       substring_index(group_concat(hour order by value asc), ',', 1) as minhour
from newtable t
group by date;
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know mysql had the case statement. I only used it with PG.

Comment: @itsols . . . The `case` statement is part of ANSI standard SQL and supported by every "real" database (okay, that is part of my definition of a "real" database).  That means that -- apart from very old versions of some databases (Oracle 8i anyone?) -- only MS Access doesn't support it.

Comment: hmmm, now I have a table with 25 column. You say 25 tables with just one column? Consider that each table need at least two columns, one for date, other for value, I tought storing everything in the same table is better. If the manipulation is complicated, then I will parse in the PHP document

Answer (score 0):

At first, thank you everyone for the help.

Finally I made the solution with PHP instead of manipulate a big SQL sentence.

I create the array using the function ObtainArrayFromSQL, and then, use the function array_search() with min() as needle in the haystack (array).

```
 function ObtainArrayFromSQL($arraySQL){
 $array = array();
 for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++)
      {
          array_push($array, $data_day[$i."h"]);
      }
 return $array;
 }
 ...

$index_lower_value =  array_search(min($array), $array);
```

Thank you everyone!